# Is there a way to tell VS Code that the firstLine match in my language extension should overrule any file extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am currently developing a language extension for VS Code. The language I am developing it for usually comes with either its own file extension (let's call it `.myext`) or simply `.txt` (it's just a scripting language).

I have run into the issue that I am not sure how to tell VS Code to use my extension when the first line matches a specific string when opening `.txt` files.

This is what I am trying (excerpt from my `package.json`):

```json
"contributes": {
  "languages": [
    {
      "id": "mylang",
      "aliases": [
        "mylang"
      ],
      "extensions": [
        ".myext"
      ],
      "firstLine": "^MyLang.*",
      "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

This does not work when I open a `.txt` file that starts with `MyLang`. It does however work if I open a file that has an unknown (e.g., `file.foobar1234`) or no extension at all.

When I now change the configuration to include `.txt` files, it will activate my extension for *any* `.txt` file I open:

```json
"contributes": {
  "languages": [
    {
      "id": "mylang",
      "aliases": [
        "mylang"
      ],
      "extensions": [
        ".myext",
        ".txt"
      ],
      "firstLine": "^MyLang.*",
      "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I do not want this, I want to keep the default `plain text` setting when opening normal `.txt` files.

In short, what I want to achieve:

- have my extension activate on my custom file extension `.myext` (this already works without any issues)
- have my extension activate when opening `.txt` files that start with the string specified via `firstLine`
- do not have my extension activate when opening `.txt` files that *do not* start with the string specified via `firstLine`

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some extensive search: this is currently not possible.

There was a recent change (mid-late 2017) that allows language extensions that match the file extension **and** the first line of a file to get precedence over an extension that just matches one of the two.

This does, however, not work with the built-in language modes of VS Code. Matching a file extension will make it so VS Code *always* chooses your language extension for such files if there if there is no other extension available for that language, regardless of any first line rule that might have been set in addition.

See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10915) and [here](https://github.com/PranayAgarwal/vscode-hack/issues/1) for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest version of VS Code, I say this because it's what I have might be probably is supported in earlier versions. On the bottom toolbar you should see the language that is auto-detected for the file you have open.  For example, if you have a .js file it will auto-config for JavaScript.  Whatever language defaults for you file, just click on it and it will bring you into 'Select Language Mode'.

From there you'll have options. You can configure/customize what happens and/or Search for an extension to fulfill the Language mode.  So, I think you'd want to do the latter especially if you're creating your own language file.

Comment: Yup, I know this, of course. You can always choose a language mode manually with this (I usually use the keyboard shortcut), but the whole goal of my extension is to get the auto-detection to a point that it's not needed to change anything manually.